# rotation problems when firing

Tags: actionscript-3, math, geometry

I have a big problem when I try to rotate my projectiles along with the ship's rotation.

I want my spaceship shoot two shots at once. So I used my first array of projectiles and placed them at the right side of the ship (one shot on the left and one on the right). So far so good.

But when I shoot with my spaceship and I turn around the rotations of the projectiles look very strange. It's hard to describe so here's an image that shows the error in action.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/projectilebug.jpg

I have huge problems rotating the projectiles ALONG with the spaceship so that it looks really good. Currently there is one single shot only. My shooting gets screwed up when I rotate and fire at once.
The goal is to create a dual firing cannon like in the picture shown.

Here is some code that places the projectile at the left of the ship (that doesn't really work):

```
var projectileRadians:Number = (player.frame / 180) * 3.14159;

tempProjectile.x = (player.point.x + 6) + Math.cos(projectileRadians);
tempProjectile.y = (player.point.y + 3) + Math.sin(projectileRadians);
```

The velocity code:

```
tempProjectile.nextX = tempProjectile.x;
tempProjectile.nextY = tempProjectile.y;
tempProjectile.dx = rotationVectorList[player.frame].x;
tempProjectile.dy = rotationVectorList[player.frame].y;
```

This updates the position:

```
nextX += (dx * (speed + Math.abs(xAdjust))) * step;
nextY += (dy * (speed + Math.abs(yAdjust))) * step;
```

Comment: The location where the projectile starts is only half the story. You also need to look at the velocity vector of the projectile. Want to post that code, too?

Comment: tempProjectile.nextX = tempProjectile.x;
tempProjectile.nextY = tempProjectile.y;
   
tempProjectile.dx = rotationVectorList[player.frame].x;
tempProjectile.dy = rotationVectorList[player.frame].y;

This updates the position:
nextX += (dx * (speed + Math.abs(xAdjust))) * step;
nextY += (dy * (speed + Math.abs(yAdjust))) * step;

Comment: ok. I'm so sorry for my late reply but in the meantime I had to do some other things. I figured out the problem!:) It was my fault. My rotation-point had incorrect values so it didn't rotate  correctly. I modified and adjusted my rotation-point and now it's working. Thanks for your help anyway!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity code looks ok. You don't seem to be calculating the gun position correctly.

Edit: we're not using the standard trig frame of reference; instead, we're using one where angle=0 means up and angles increase as you rotate clockwise. So we take the standard usage and swap *sin* and *cos*.

Here, `gx` and `gy` mean the coordinates of a gun relative to the coordinates around which the ship moves. We need to rotate the vector <gx, gy> by the angle before adding it to the ship coords:

```
cs = Math.cos(projectileRadians);
sn = Math.sin(projectileRadians);
tempProjectile.x = player.point.x + gx * sn - gy * cs;
tempProjectile.y = player.point.y + gx * cs + gy * sn;
```

It would be a good optimization to restrict the ship's angle to certain values (perhaps every 5 degrees), and put all the trig functions into a table ahead of time. Trig functions are expensive to compute.

Note that this also assumes that positive Y is "up". Computer graphics often start with (0, 0) in the upper left corner and increase Y as you move down, so you may have to switch the sign of Y.

Comment: Hm, not really working. See this pic what I mean: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/rotation.jpg

Currently my code looks like this:

var projectileRadians:Number = (player.frame / 180) * Math.PI;     
        
var cs:Number = Math.cos(projectileRadians);
var sn:Number = Math.sin(projectileRadians);
    
var gunX:int = 8;
var gunY:int = 8;
    
var gunPoint:Point = new Point(gunX, gunY);
       
tempProjectile.x = (player.point.x + player.bitmapSize / 2) +  gunPoint.x * cs - gunPoint.y * sn;
tempProjectile.y = (player.point.y + player.bitmapSize / 2) + gunPoint.x * sn + gunPoint.y * cs;

Comment: Here's some more code (you can edit it if you like): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DOdpZQP3BANhgFAsqm__fWbi3G2I5iYVHukTQPF7yQE/edit?hl=en_US

Comment: Well, in the beginning of the video you can see that the shots are placed at the right side of the ship. So far so good (that was intended by me). But during the rotation the shots move from the right side to the center of the ship. This is the bug. I'm not very good at maths. Currently I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Was I right about angle 0 being to the right and increasing counterclockwise?

Comment: Just quoting the book where I took the source code from:
"The player's ship is facing up. We want this to be the 0 rotation value. Flash uses the facing-right value as the 0 rotation. By passing 90 in as the offset we can mitigate this behavior and create the correct rotation values for our object."

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.:) I will try that in the next few days because in the meantime I have to do some other things. When it's working I'll let you know...